# UPDATE обновляет все записи (строки) вместо одной

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть таблица `users` с полями `userid` с типом данных `TEXT` и `message` с типом данных `INT`.

И есть бот который читает сообщения в чате и с каждым новым сообщением добавляет в поле `message` +1 к значению.

```
db = sqlite3.connect("messages.db")
sql = db.cursor()
sql.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (userid TEXT, message INT)")
db.commit()

class Bot:

    def message_count(self, userid):
        sql.execute("SELECT COUNT(userid) FROM users WHERE userid=(?)", (userid,))
        for value in sql:
            if value[0] == 0:
                sql.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)", (userid, 1))
                db.commit()
            else:
                sql.execute("UPDATE users SET message = message+1")
                db.commit()
```

Проблема в том, что `sql.execute("UPDATE users SET message = message+1")`, при каждом новом сообщении добавляет +1 всем пользователям в таблице, а не только тому, кто это сообщение написал.

Comment: `sql.execute("UPDATE users SET message = message + 1 WHERE userid = ?", (userid,))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в SQL операции обновления таблицы (`UPDATE tab_name ...`) не указать условие выбора записей - `WHERE ...` , то данная операция применится ко *всем* строкам таблицы `tab_name`. Именно это и происходит в вашем случае.

Поэтому, укажите условие выбора записей для `UPDATE` при помощи предиката `WHERE ...`:

```
sql.execute("UPDATE users SET message = message + 1 WHERE userid = ?", (userid,))
```